# Are ISODateTimeFormat formatters performant under heavy concurrency?

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, jodatime

From the [javadocs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html), it is explicitly specified that

> ISODateTimeFormat is thread-safe and immutable, and the formatters it returns are as well.

It is not clear, however, if instances are expected to perform well under heavy concurrency. Are there any points of synchronization or lock contention? If I expect to have hundreds (or thousands) of threads performing DateTime parsing and formatting, is it better to provide each thread with its own DateTimeFormatter instance or would can I expect the same performance by sharing the same instance among all the threads (with the added bonus of saving a little memory)?

Comment: Maybe you should not have so many active threads, unless the wait/sleep a lot. Try ThreadLocals for formatters.

Answer (score 0):

A quick scan of the Joda codebase suggests that you shouldn't have any issues with multiple threads using the same `DateTimeFormatter`as there are no methods in it that are synchronized.  Synchronization in Joda mainly sits in cache access methods for creators.  Although, of course, if you have a server with enough cores to test a situation with this many threads then it should be trivial to put together a benchmark to confirm it.